# Summing Total JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the value of each of the three scores and add them up and display them in "Total:". My problem is that I cannot figure out how to make it so that every time one of the score values change, the corresponding total changes with it.

Would I be able to somehow invoke "onchange" somewhere to make this work? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="getTotal.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Total: 
            <output id="total" class="totalScore"></output>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </header>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <td>Score 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="score1"/></td>

      <td>Score 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="score2" /></td>

      <td>Score 3</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="score3" /></td>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<script type="text/javascript">assign();</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript class getTotal.js

```
function total() {
    var score1 = document.getElementById("score1");
    var score2 = document.getElementById("score2");
    var score3 = document.getElementById("score3");

    return score1 + score2 + score3;
}

function assign() {
    var totalScore = document.getElementById("total");
    totalScore = total;
}
```

Comment: First off, please learn about `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`. Secondly, look into the `value` property of DOM elements. Finally, check out the `onchange` or `onkeyup` events.

Answer (score 1):

Your code 'as is' won't work. As I mentioned in my comment, you need to look at [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) (or [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) depending upon the values you allow), and also the `value` property of DOM objects. Finally, [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onchange) or [`onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onkeyup) events can be used for user interaction.

Combining all of these will give you the following, working sample:

```
var score1Field = document.getElementById('score1'),
    score2Field = document.getElementById('score2'),
    score3Field = document.getElementById('score3');

function sumit()
{
    var score1 = parseFloat( score1Field.value ),
        score2 = parseFloat( score2Field.value ),
        score3 = parseFloat( score3Field.value );

    if( isNaN( score1 ) ) { score1 = 0; }
    if( isNaN( score2 ) ) { score2 = 0; }
    if( isNaN( score3 ) ) { score3 = 0; }

    total = score1 + score2 + score3;

    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
}

// Bind our events:
score1Field.onkeyup = sumit;
score2Field.onkeyup = sumit;
score3Field.onkeyup = sumit;

// Call it when the page loads to handle default values:
sumit();
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1vpxt7y8/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use an [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange) event to recalculate when the value changes (after you focus away from the input), or use [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) if you want it to recalculate as you type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use onchange and wrap your total() and assign() functions inside it.
See this link for onchange usage: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp